# Selenium 3.0.1 -interactive gives ParameterException: Unknown option: -interactive

Tags: java, selenium, webautomation

How to run selenum standanlone jar in interactive mode so that we can trigger commands from terminal. When I run as shown below exception occurs

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -interactive
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: -interactive
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:742)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:282)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:265)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.<init>(JCommander.java:210)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3$1.setConfiguration(GridLauncherV3.java:219)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.buildLauncher(GridLauncherV3.java:147)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:73)
```

However I am able to run `version 2.48.2` in the above manner and it works fine.

Answer (score 6):

starting version 3, the selenium team changed the available configuration options (see [an example configuration](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultNodeWebDriver.json)), as well as [replaced the command line arguments parser to JCommander](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2566#issuecomment-237424543).

the implications are;

- some options may not be available anymore, or their names have changed. looking at [the V3 example configuration](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultNodeWebDriver.json), it seems the support for `-interactive` has dropped.
- you should specify all `-D` arguments first, i.e. right after the `java` command.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the info I needed.